# Make GAIM (Pidgin) wait longer before starting new logfile for idle chat?

Tags: pidgin

If I'm chatting w/ someone via GAIM, and the chat idles for a certain 
amount of time, GAIM creates a new logfile when the chat resumes. Example from /home/barrycarter/.gaim/logs/jabber/carter.barry@gmail.com/id-of-person/

```
2010-06-10.094139-0600MDT.txt [mod time: 2010-06-10 14:35]
2010-06-08.140656-0600MDT.txt [mod time: 2010-06-08 16:00]
```

These are actually the same conversation, with a gap from "2010-06-08 
16:00" to "2010-06-10 09:41:39". How would I tell GAIM: "if the 
conversation idle is less than `<n>` hours, don't create a new log 
file?"

Note: The above is just an example: in reality, I probably wouldn't 
want the same log file after a 2 day gap (a 20 hour gap, maybe).

Comment: I thought Pidgin creates a logfile for each time you open/close the conversation window?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. You appear to be correct. Turn into an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pidgin (former GAIM) does not create it's logfiles (curiously still located in `~/.gaim/logs/PROTOCOL/ACCOUNT/`) based on a time gap within a conversation. It considers a conversation ongoing as long as you keep the conversation window open. If you close and open the conversation window, there will be a new logfile created for that 'new' conversation.